# Active candidate-pair change not being detected by the other peer

Tags: webrtc

I was looking at a call between two peers.

`Peer 1` began the session using:

```
{
  localCandidate: { type: 'serverreflexive' },
  remoteCandidate: { type: 'relayed' }
}
```

`Peer 2` also settled on the same:

```
{
  localCandidate: { type: 'relayed' },
  remoteCandidate: { type: 'serverreflexive' }
}
```

However 5 seconds in, `peer 1` changed to a peer reflexive candidate:

```
{
  localCandidate: { type: 'relayed'},
  remoteCandidate: { type: 'peerreflexive' }
}
```

This behaviour is expected. However, `peer 2` remained on the old pair and the call effectively failed with no transmission of data between `peer 2` and `peer 1`.

Two questions if you dont mind:

1. Why is `peer reflexive` preferable over the `server reflexive` candidate? I assume one has a lower weight than the other, but why would that be?
2. What are some reasons that `peer 2` could not detect the active candidate change? Could it be signalling failed or perhaps a version discrepancy between the two WebRTC stacks? Or is signalling not even used when a peer reflexive candidate is selected?

If it matters, this was a call between Android WebRTC and webrtcbin (https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/webrtc/index.html).

Comment: without pcaps from both ends this is going to be hard to explain...
Note that prflx has a higher priority than srflx and is not signalled

Comment: Ah that's what I expected. Since the stun message/response make it to both sides, no signalling is required. Okay that at least narrows down the problem surface. When a pair is marked as active, does this imply the other side knows about it or is it marked as active before letting the other peer know that is the case?

Comment: see the description of the use-candidate attribute in RFC 5245

Comment: I came across this: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libnice/libnice/-/issues/135. Supposedly the pair cannot change without a renegotiation. That would mean that if `srflx` is marked as active first, and then changes to `prflx` without a renegotiation, the call will fail. Libnice respects the RFC while WebRTC implementation might not?

Comment: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8445#section-8.1.1